# Integrals - Prove Molecules Median Velocity (Medium level)

Tags: calculus

Would you mind helping me?

The median velocity of ideal gases molecules is
$Vm = \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}(\frac{M}{2RT}^{\frac{3}{2}})\int_0^\infty{v^3e^{\frac{-Mv^2}{2RT}}dv}$
M: molecular weight of the gas
R: Gas Constant
T: Gas Tempeture
v: Molecular Velocity

Prove that
$V = \sqrt{\frac{8RT}{\pi M}}$

Comment: Hint: You can use integration by parts twice, i.e., $Vm = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}(\frac{M}{2RT})^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^\infty{v^2 (2 \frac{M}{2RT} v e^{\frac{-Mv^2}{2RT}})dv}$

Answer (score 0):

Just make a change of variables:
$$y = \dfrac{Mv^2}{2RT}$$
Pull out all constants; you should be left with $C\int ye^{-y} dy$.